# url masking via htaccess rewrite is not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, masking

Not sure if this is the right section of Stackoverflow to ask my question...

But here it is:

So I am using the below on the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sale?$ /discount-page/
```

So that when people visit `example.com/sale` page, they see content from `example.com/discount-page/`

But when I visit `example.com/sale` it shows 404 error saying that the URL `/discount-page` is not available on this server...

Why is it happening?

Here's how my entire `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

When using WordPress, you can't simply rewrite the URL in `.htaccess` to the `%postname%` (the real URL) since WP still looks at the `REQUEST_URI` in order to route the URL. Even though you are rewriting `/sale` to `/discount-page/` (the actual URL), WordPress sees `/sale` (the requested URL) - which doesn't exist inside WP; hence the 404.

Although not your intention, you could change this to an external redirect to get around this problem (which also avoids a potential duplicate content issue). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^sale$ /discount-page/ [R,L]
```

(I removed the `?` in `^sale?$`, as that does look erroneous. Or do you really want to match `/sale` or `/sal`?)

Alternatively, you could try rewriting to the underlying "plain" permalink. ie. explicitly pass the `%post_id%`. This is different to rewriting to the `%postname%`, since WP shouldn't need to check the `REQUEST_URI` in order to route the URL. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^sale$ /index.php?p=123 [L]
```

Where `123` is the `%post_id%` of your `discount-page`. By rewriting directly to `index.php`, you are effectively bypassing WP's front-controller.

Note that this must go *before* the standard WordPress directives in `.htaccess` (aka the front-controller).

---

However, I still feel there should be a more WordPress-like way of doing this, which is why I initially suggested asking this question over on the [WordPress Stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). However, if you do that, don't mention ".htaccess". What you are really creating is a URL alias or something like that. For example: [Have two different URLs show the homepage](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300833/have-two-different-urls-show-the-homepage)

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried RewriteRule ^sale$ /index.php?p=123 [L] but it didn't work. I still see the /sale url in the address bar. Also, i still see contents from /sale and not /discount-page